# how to use llvm analysis pass in standalone program?

Tags: c++, llvm

I want to use llvm alias analysis result in my standalone program, for example, maybe like this initially:

```
int main()
{
  ...
  PassManager PM(M);
  ImmutablePass* basic_aa = createBasicAliasAnalysisPass();
  PM.add(basic_aa);
  AliasAnalysis& AA = basic_aa->getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>();
  ...
}
```

but the AA seems to make no sense. So how can I use llvm analysis pass in my standalone program?

Answer (score 0):

llvm Analysis is not a pass but passes, that being said.

AA class is used to determine whether or not two pointers ever can point to the same object in memory.Traditionally, alias analyses respond to a query with a Must, May, or No alias response, indicating that two pointers always point to the same object, might point to the same object, or are known to never point to the same object

Example:

if you want to search for un-aliased global memory buffers that are only read from and pull them into the constant address space, you can create array of those pointer and Check for aliasing against non-read-only inputs.

```
AA->alias(psAVal, psBVal) != AliasResult::NoAlias
```

See:
http://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html